# Convergence in probability of Cesaro sums

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I saw in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931277/convergence-in-probability-and-convergence-of-cesaro-means) that for an independent sequence $\{X_n\}$, such that $X_n=2^n,$ with probability $1/n$,and $X_n=0$ with probability $1-1/n$ the sequence converges in probability to zero but the cesaro sum $\frac{X_1+X_2+\ldots X_n}{n}$ does not converge in probability. I see that the sequence itself converges to 0 because
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n| \geq \epsilon)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$$
But I dont understand how to get the same for the Cesaro sum. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Try to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|\frac{X_1+X_2+\ldots X_n}{n}| \leq \epsilon)$

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. Do I have to use union bound somehow?

Comment: Well, I think it is just the probability that every $X_n = 0$ (when $n$ is large enough)

Comment: I see. Is there a way to make this rigorous?

Comment: Well, I apologize for my mistake, I misunderstood your question. The statement in my last comment should be "most $X_n = 0$", to make it rigorous, just consider the smallest integer $k$ such that $\frac{2^k}{n} \geq \epsilon$, and $X_m$ must be zero if $k\leq m \leq n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S_n=X_1+\dots+X_n$. In order to prove that $S_n/n$ does not converge in probability, we shall show that $S_n/n$ is not Cauchy in probability. Specifically, we show that
$$
P(|S_n/n-S_{2n}/2n| \ge 1) \not \to 0\qquad \text{as }n\to\infty
$$
To this end, suppose that there exists an index $k$ such that

- $k\ge n+1+\log_2 n$, and
- $X_k=2^k$.

I claim, in this case, that $|S_n/n-S_{2n}/2n|\ge 1$. Proof:
$$
\begin{align}
|S_n/n-S_{2n}/n|
  &\ge |S_{2n}/2n|-|S_n/n|
\\&\ge |2^k/2n|-|2^{n+1}/n|
\\&=\frac1n(2^{k-1}-2^n)
\\&\ge \frac1n(2^{n+\log_2 n}-2^n)
\\&=2^n(1-1/n)
\\&\ge 1 \tag{for $n\ge 2$}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we can lower bound the probability of $|S_n/n-S_{2n}/2n|\ge 1$ by the probability of the existence of such a $k$.  Each of the variables in the list
$$
X_{n+1+\log_2 n},\dots,X_{2n}
$$ is zero with probability at most $1-1/2n$. Therefore,
$$
P(|S_n/n-S_{2n}/2n|\ge 1) \ge 1 - \left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{n-\log_2 n-1}
$$
Since $$\lim_{n\to\infty}1 - \left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)^{n-\log_2 n-1}=1-e^{-1/2},$$
we conclude that $S_n/n$ is not Cauchy in probability.